# What could be causing a ClassNotFoundException?

Tags: android, runtime-error, classnotfoundexception

So I've been working on an app lately which runs fine on most devices. However, sometimes the app crashes at start up with the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity
ComponentInfo{com.mypackage.app/com.mypackage.app.activities.MainPager}:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mypackage.app.activities.MainPager
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1995)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2096)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:138)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1207)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4787)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576)
at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:115)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
com.mypackage.app.activities.MainPager
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1053)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1986)
... 12 more
```

I get that this is because it can't find the class called MainPager. But how is that even possible? I mean, the class should be there.. I put it there myself :) . Why on earth is it not finding it?

**EDIT:** I think the cause may be that in my manifest I have `android:package="com.mypackage.app"` defined, but that my launch activity is in the package `com.mypackage.app.activities`. Currently testing this theory. Still weird that it only happens on some devices, though.

This solution won't work, since I then can't update the APK in Google Play (has to be the same package name in the manifest).

Comment: Did you add the activity class into manifest?

Comment: Yes I did :) . And it's working fine on most devices, it's only some that it crashes on.

Comment: try add activity with its package name like `com.mypackage.app.activities.MainPager`

Comment: It actually already was in the manifest like that, so that can't be it :)

Comment: For the devices, this crashes. Do they have something in common, like Android version or the like?

Comment: They're all very new phones like Galaxy S4, Galaxy S3 and Xperia T. They all have Android 4.1, 4.2 or 4.3.

Answer (score 0):

Since ADT update to revision 22 (May 2013) you have to check "Android Private Libraries" check box in Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Order and Export in Eclipse for your older projects to get rid of this exception ...

Comment: It already was checked, but the error still persists on some devices

Answer (score 0):

in the manifest you add Activity name like this

```
android:name=".activities.MainPager"
```

because you have given package name

```
android:package="com.mypackage.app"
```

Comment: It's already in there as `com.mypackage.app.activities.MainPager`, so that should be fine right?

Answer (score 0):

Now I am using ART runtime on Nexus 5, and I am getting ClassNotFound for some apps.

You can safely ignore those if that's the case for your users.